# Rename map keys in GSON according to FieldNamingPolicy

Tags: java, json, gson

Say I'm building my GSON object like this

```
new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
```

and now I want to deserialize the following JSON

```
{
    "MyMap" : {
        "Key1" : "Foo",
        "Key2" : "Bar"
    }
}
```

into the following class (which is working just fine)

```
public class MapClass {
    Map<String,String> myMap;
}
```

but I also would like the keys to be named "key1" and "key2". How would I go about this?

Comment: Why don't you iterate over myMap map after deserialization and replace Key1 to key1 and Key2 with key2?

Comment: That's obviously one way. But I use the GSON object throughout the whole project and would like to have it automatically.

Comment: FieldNamingPolicy is applied to fields. hashmap values are not fiedls so it's normal that FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE is only applied to MyMap. Anyway, you can write a custom TypeAdapter and manage serialize deserialize process. (renaming map's keys would be much more easier to this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{"
                    + "    \"MyMap\" : {"
                    + "        \"Key1\" : \"Foo\","
                    + "        \"Key2\" : \"Bar\""
                    + "    }"
                    + "}"); // this parses the json
            JSONObject jObjt = jObj.getJSONObject("MyMap");

           //old version with out GSON
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
            Iterator itr = jObjt.keys();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) itr.next();
                String value = jObjt.getString(key);
                map.put(key, value);
            }

           //desalinized one with GSON             
           Map<String, String> map1 = new Gson().fromJson(jObjt.toString(), HashMap.class);
           for (String str : map1.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("k:" + str + " v:" + map1.get(str));
           }


        } catch (JSONException ex) {
           //log the error
    }
```

Comment: If I did this by hand, I wouldn't need to use GSON. Besides the data will be dynamicly structured.

Comment: you can desalinize it to a Map like: HashMap<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jObjt.toString(), HashMap.class);  I just Edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

`FieldNamingPolicy` is applied to fields of json value. It is not possible to apply this to  maps' keys (a map which has key, value pairs) at json.

**Easy solution:**
After deserialization, iterate over your map and rename key names. i.e. Key1 to key1 and Key2 to key2.

**Other solution:**

Write a custom TypeAdapter which handles deserialization process and renames keys.

```
public class MapClassTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MapClass> {

    @Override
    public MapClass read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final MapClass mapClassInstance = new MapClass();
        mapClassInstance.myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        in.beginObject();

        if("myMap".equalsIgnoreCase(in.nextName())) {
            in.beginObject();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String key = in.nextName();
                // You want keys as camel case
                String newKey = key.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + key.substring(1);
                String value = in.nextString();

                mapClassInstance.myMap.put(newKey, value);
            }
            in.endObject();
        }
        in.endObject();
        return mapClassInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, MapClass mapClass) throws IOException {
        throw new RuntimeException("MapClassTypeAdapter.write method not implemented yet!");
    }
}
```

**Test Other solution:**

```
String json = "{\"myMap\":{\"Key1\":\"Foo\",\"Key2\":\"Bar\"}}";

final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MapClass.class, new MapClassTypeAdapter());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

MapClass mapClass = gson.fromJson(json, MapClass.class);
```